# How do you calculate standard deviation for a mean change, given mean 1, SD 1, mean 2, SD 2, and total n?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, standard-deviation, meta-analysis, biostatistics

How do you calculate standard deviation for a mean change, given mean 1, SD 1, mean 2, SD 2, and total n?

For example: n=590. Initial mean is 26 with a standard deviation of 8. The mean at the end point is 32 with a standard deviation of 10. So the mean change is 6 with a standard deviation of X?

I'm doing a meta-analysis in R using the meta package (metacont) function, so I don't have access to the raw data (only summary statistics from each study).

I've been digging around a lot and it seems that maybe this is impossible to calculate exactly without the correlation between mean 1 and mean 2. However, even if there is a way to do a pretty good estimate, it would help me finish my analysis.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We usually calculate this in Excel and then use the 'change from baseline' score (and SD) for further analysis. Cochrane has a good explanation and examples: https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_1_3_2_imputing_standard_deviations_for_changes_from_baseline.htm (former handbook) and https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-06#section-6-5-2-8 (current handbook - you may need to register)

Comment: That makes sense and is very helpful. Thank you!